# Form.Closing not listed as event for form?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, events

I'm using Visual Studio 2010; usually when I want to add events other than mouse clicks I go to to the events tab and find the event, click it, and it takes me to that spot in code.

However, I can't find any for the `Closing` event of the form.

I've tried manually adding it in but I think there's more behind the scenes stuff that VS is taking care of:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{

}
```

What's the most effective way for having everything 'written' for the `FormClosing` event? Or how do I enter it all manually if I must?

This is form WinForms.

Comment: It's called `FormClosing`, not `Closing` (and then I see the answers and see it's already answered there! :-) )

Comment: Strange indeed because in the form section of my designer it reads : this.Closing +=  ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called `FormClosing` not `Closing`.  You can add the event by going to the properties window and clicking on the "Events" button then double-clicking on the "FormClosing" item:

[image]

You're almost there with what you have.  What you're missing is the code-behind that wires up the event to your handler, which is automatically generated for you when you follow the above procedure.  Here's what it looks like in the `InitializeComponent` method in the "Form1.Designer.cs" file (click the "Show All Files" button on the top of the Solution Explorer):

```
this.FormClosing += 
    new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add the method `Form1_FormClosing` manually, You should add the following line of code in the constructor :

```
this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);
```

For the form close event:

Click on the form -> Properties -> Events -> Form Closing